# How to achieve plugin architecture in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i am trying to figure out how to achieve something like a plugin architecture for my zend framework application.

Let's say i have a upload formular for some documents. If there is no "plugin" i want to have some default uploads to my webserver. However if i do insert my "specific-upload-plugin" i want the files to be uploaded to sharepoint (just as an example).

But i really want to achieve this without changing much code at all. I would be fine with changing some config file but i shouldnt need to change any controller code at all.

Can someone point me out some tutorials or methods on how i will be able to achieve that? Or just some best practices on that kind of task?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to extend `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` which is the adapter that is used for handling a standard `File` upload element in Zend Framework.

All you may need to do is overload the `receive()` method to receive the file but instead of moving the file to a permanent location on the server, you could have your adapter upload to sharepoint, or take care of moving the file to the final destination wherever it may be.

Your constructor could set adapter specific options such as sharepoint IP address and credentials and any other options you need.

This way, no changes need to be made to the controller, you would simply modify your `Zend_Form` object to use a `File` element but give it your custom transfer adapter.  All validation and error handling is done by Zend_Form, and your adapter takes care of the details of putting the file where it needs to go and any errors encountered there can be passed back to the form.  Therefore, there is no need to change any controller code; all that logic lives in your transfer adapter and form.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i wasn't clear enough or maybe i dont yet understand your suggestion. Aside from that upload thing, i want to achieve a plugin architecture. Imagine me having a "/plugin" folger at my ZF Project root. If inside that folder i place another folder with a plugin, e.g "/sharepoint_upload" with the files inside that controller i want to change the default behavior of my application. In here the upload thing is just an example. It can basicaly be anything. I don't know if that's even possible at all, cuz i can't imagine how it would work at all :) But thank you for your answer, its noted

Comment: I see.  Given the upload example it doesn't seem possible without replacing the file transfer adapter with a custom one.  ZF has a [plugin architecture](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) already that can run code at various points in the application, but that may or may not help you.  It sounds like in some ways you are going for a hook style system that can check to see if a hook is registered to run at a particular point in the controller, but I'm not sure if that is it.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the late reply! But yeah i guess "Hook" might actually be the right word. And given what ZF provides, i don't think that a drag and drop method can work without building in advance. I think when writing my code i have to guess in advance if there can be a plugin or not. Like `$uploader = $this->getUploader()` whereas getUploader() is a function who checks the "plugin/uploader" folder. If its empty or non existant use the default method, if it exists use the new one. Thank you anyways! :)